# android facebook upload multiple images to "group wall"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am developing an android app with social functions.
I would like to have a function which they can upload multiple photos to a private group within a post.

Something like this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMIBg.png

I've done some research for open graph and android api for fb. I use RequestBatch to separate different pictures but facebook did not merge them into one post.
I also use WebDialog to publish a post but I can't find a way to let the FeedDialog to point to the group wall.
I did lots of survey on Google but can't figure out any work solutions.

If there's any one know how to do this or give me some examples, It'll be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

//////////////////// 1st way: send batch requests to fb, I thought it will merge them into one post but not...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("http://example.url:8000/uploads/images1.jpg");
list.add("http://example.url:8000/uploads/images2.jpg");
list.add("http://example.url:8000/uploads/images3.jpg");
int index = 0;
RequestBatch reqBatch = new RequestBatch();
do {
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("picture", list.get(index).toString());
    postParams.putString("message", "message");
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),"group_id/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST);
    request.setCallback( new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, ""+response);
        }
    });
    reqBatch.add(request);
    index++;
}while(list.size()>index);
reqBatch.executeAsync();
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 2nd way: get a webDialog

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "name");
params.putString("caption", "caption");
params.putString("description", "TEST");
params.putString("link", "http://image.url/image.jpg");
params.putString("to", "group_id");  // how to change to group wall???? and how to set 2+ photos???

WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
        Session.getActiveSession(),params)).setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, values.toString());
        }

    })
    .build();
feedDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share multiple images with facebook apps.

```
protected void share(String nameApp, String imagePath, String text) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

try { 
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getActivity().getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
            Intent targetedShare = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            targetedShare.setType("image/png"); // put here your mime
            // type 
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(
                    nameApp)
                    || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(
                            nameApp)) {
                targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
                targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                for(int j= 0;j<caminhos.size();j++){
                    if(!caminhos.get(j).isEmpty()){
                        File file = new File(caminhos.get(j));
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        files.add(uri);
                    } 
                } 

                targetedShare.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        files);
                targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
            } 
        } 
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
} 
}
```